# Avoiding this use of sapply in R data.table

Tags: regex, r, data.table, vectorization, sapply

I've written a function to remove everything from the first parentheses onwards in a string:

```
until_parentheses <- function(string) {

  one <- stringr::str_split_fixed(string, "\\(", 2)[1, 1]

  res <- stringr::str_trim(one)

  return(res)

}
```

And I have a data.table with a column that looks (something) like this:

```
messy <- paste(letters[1:10], paste0(c(" (", letters[1:2], ")"), collapse = ""))

dt <- data.table(messy)
```

When I try to use `until_parentheses()` on the messy column like so

```
dt[, ":=" (clean = until_parentheses(messy))]
```

The function is applied to only the first element of messy and the clean column is the result repeated 10 times.

In order to have the clean column come out how I want it to I am using sapply:

```
dt[, ":=" (clean_2 = sapply(messy, until_parentheses))]
```

This gives the result I want however it takes a long time to run when dt is long.

I feel like there are problems with both my `until_parenthese()` function and with my data.table method. Does anyone have a solution that makes redundant my use of sapply in this instance?

Thanks!

Comment: Your function is written so that you return only the first result (row). `[1, 1]` should be `[, 1]`, and  then `sapply()` is not necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gsub` which is vectorized:

```
dt[,clean_3:=gsub(' +[(].*','',messy)] ## replace anything after the first ( with a blank
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to improve my regex knowledge.